# Can't find CharacterMotor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please help. I'm adding a run and crouch script to the standard FPS character controller and get the following error message:  error CS0246: The type or namespace name `CharacterMotor' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

```
public class RunAndCrouch : MonoBehaviour {

public float walkSpeed = 7; // regular speed
 public float crchSpeed = 3; // crouching speed
 public float runSpeed = 20; // run speed

 private CharacterMotor chMotor;
 private Transform tr;
 private float dist; // distance to ground

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () 
 {
     chMotor =  GetComponent<CharacterMotor>();
     tr = transform;
     CharacterController ch = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
     dist = ch.height/2; // calculate distance to ground
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void FixedUpdate ()
 {
     float vScale = 1.0f;
     float speed = walkSpeed;

     if ((Input.GetKey("left shift") || Input.GetKey("right shift")) &&   chMotor.grounded)
     {
         speed = runSpeed;            
     }

     if (Input.GetKey("c"))
     { // press C to crouch
         vScale = 0.5f;
         speed = crchSpeed; // slow down when crouching
     }

     chMotor.movement.maxForwardSpeed = speed; // set max speed
     float ultScale = tr.localScale.y; // crouch/stand up smoothly 

     Vector3 tmpScale = tr.localScale;
     Vector3 tmpPosition = tr.position;

     tmpScale.y = Mathf.Lerp(tr.localScale.y, vScale, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
     tr.localScale = tmpScale;

     tmpPosition.y += dist * (tr.localScale.y - ultScale); // fix vertical position        
     tr.position = tmpPosition;
 }
```

}

FPSControllerScript (this is the FPS character from Unity's standard assets)

```
    using System;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
    using UnityStandardAssets.Utility;
    using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

    namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
    {
    [RequireComponent(typeof (CharacterController))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof (AudioSource))]
    public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private bool m_IsWalking;
        [SerializeField] private float m_WalkSpeed;
        [SerializeField] private float m_RunSpeed;
        [SerializeField] [Range(0f, 1f)] private float m_RunstepLenghten;
        [SerializeField] private float m_JumpSpeed;
        [SerializeField] private float m_StickToGroundForce;
        [SerializeField] private float m_GravityMultiplier;
        [SerializeField] private MouseLook m_MouseLook;
        [SerializeField] private bool m_UseFovKick;
        [SerializeField] private FOVKick m_FovKick = new FOVKick();
        [SerializeField] private bool m_UseHeadBob;
        [SerializeField] private CurveControlledBob m_HeadBob = new CurveControlledBob();
        [SerializeField] private LerpControlledBob m_JumpBob = new LerpControlledBob();
        [SerializeField] private float m_StepInterval;
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] m_FootstepSounds;    // an array of footstep sounds that will be randomly selected from.
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip m_JumpSound;           // the sound played when character leaves the ground.
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip m_LandSound;           // the sound played when character touches back on ground.

        //MY INPUT

        public float pushPower = 2.0F;
        private Camera m_Camera;
        private bool m_Jump;
        private float m_YRotation;
        private Vector2 m_Input;
        private Vector3 m_MoveDir = Vector3.zero;
        private CharacterController m_CharacterController;
        private CollisionFlags m_CollisionFlags;
        private bool m_PreviouslyGrounded;
        private Vector3 m_OriginalCameraPosition;
        private float m_StepCycle;
        private float m_NextStep;
        private bool m_Jumping;
        private AudioSource m_AudioSource;

        // Use this for initialization
        private void Start()
        {
            m_CharacterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            m_Camera = Camera.main;
            m_OriginalCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
            m_FovKick.Setup(m_Camera);
            m_HeadBob.Setup(m_Camera, m_StepInterval);
            m_StepCycle = 0f;
            m_NextStep = m_StepCycle/2f;
            m_Jumping = false;
            m_AudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            m_MouseLook.Init(transform , m_Camera.transform);
        }



        private void Update()
        {
            RotateView();
            // the jump state needs to read here to make sure it is notmissed

            if (!m_Jump)
            {
                m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
            }

            if (!m_PreviouslyGrounded && m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
            {
                StartCoroutine(m_JumpBob.DoBobCycle());
                PlayLandingSound();
                m_MoveDir.y = 0f;
                m_Jumping = false;
            }
            if (!m_CharacterController.isGrounded && !m_Jumping &        m_PreviouslyGrounded)
            {
                m_MoveDir.y = 0f;
            }

            m_PreviouslyGrounded = m_CharacterController.isGrounded;
        }


        private void PlayLandingSound()
        {
            m_AudioSource.clip = m_LandSound;
            m_AudioSource.Play();
            m_NextStep = m_StepCycle + .5f;
        }


        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            float speed;
            GetInput(out speed);
            // always move along the camera forward as it is the direction that it being aimed at
            Vector3 desiredMove = transform.forward*m_Input.y + transform.right*m_Input.x;

            // get a normal for the surface that is being touched to move along it
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, m_CharacterController.radius, Vector3.down, out hitInfo,
                               m_CharacterController.height/2f, Physics.AllLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);
            desiredMove = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(desiredMove, hitInfo.normal).normalized;

            m_MoveDir.x = desiredMove.x*speed;
            m_MoveDir.z = desiredMove.z*speed;


            if (m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
            {
                m_MoveDir.y = -m_StickToGroundForce;

                if (m_Jump)
                {
                    m_MoveDir.y = m_JumpSpeed;
                    PlayJumpSound();
                    m_Jump = false;
                    m_Jumping = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m_MoveDir += Physics.gravity*m_GravityMultiplier*Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            }
            m_CollisionFlags = m_CharacterController.Move(m_MoveDir*Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            ProgressStepCycle(speed);
            UpdateCameraPosition(speed);

            m_MouseLook.UpdateCursorLock();
        }


        private void PlayJumpSound()
        {
            m_AudioSource.clip = m_JumpSound;
            m_AudioSource.Play();
        }


        private void ProgressStepCycle(float speed)
        {
            if (m_CharacterController.velocity.sqrMagnitude > 0 && (m_Input.x != 0 || m_Input.y != 0))
            {
                m_StepCycle += (m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude + (speed*(m_IsWalking ? 1f : m_RunstepLenghten)))*
                             Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            }

            if (!(m_StepCycle > m_NextStep))
            {
                return;
            }

            m_NextStep = m_StepCycle + m_StepInterval;

            PlayFootStepAudio();
        }


        private void PlayFootStepAudio()
        {
            if (!m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
            {
                return;
            }
            // pick & play a random footstep sound from the array,
            // excluding sound at index 0
            int n = Random.Range(1, m_FootstepSounds.Length);
            m_AudioSource.clip = m_FootstepSounds[n];
            m_AudioSource.PlayOneShot(m_AudioSource.clip);
            // move picked sound to index 0 so it's not picked next time
            m_FootstepSounds[n] = m_FootstepSounds[0];
            m_FootstepSounds[0] = m_AudioSource.clip;
        }


        private void UpdateCameraPosition(float speed)
        {
            Vector3 newCameraPosition;
            if (!m_UseHeadBob)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude > 0 && m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
            {
                m_Camera.transform.localPosition =
                    m_HeadBob.DoHeadBob(m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude +
                                      (speed*(m_IsWalking ? 1f : m_RunstepLenghten)));
                newCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
                newCameraPosition.y = m_Camera.transform.localPosition.y - m_JumpBob.Offset();
            }
            else
            {
                newCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
                newCameraPosition.y = m_OriginalCameraPosition.y - m_JumpBob.Offset();
            }
            m_Camera.transform.localPosition = newCameraPosition;
        }


        private void GetInput(out float speed)
        {
            // Read input
            float horizontal = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            float vertical = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");

            bool waswalking = m_IsWalking;

#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            // On standalone builds, walk/run speed is modified by a key press.
            // keep track of whether or not the character is walking or running
            m_IsWalking = !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
#endif
            // set the desired speed to be walking or running
            speed = m_IsWalking ? m_WalkSpeed : m_RunSpeed;
            m_Input = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);

            // normalize input if it exceeds 1 in combined length:
            if (m_Input.sqrMagnitude > 1)
            {
                m_Input.Normalize();
            }

            // handle speed change to give an fov kick
            // only if the player is going to a run, is running and the fovkick is to be used
            if (m_IsWalking != waswalking && m_UseFovKick && m_CharacterController.velocity.sqrMagnitude > 0)
            {
                StopAllCoroutines();
                StartCoroutine(!m_IsWalking ? m_FovKick.FOVKickUp() : m_FovKick.FOVKickDown());
            }
        }


        private void RotateView()
        {
            m_MouseLook.LookRotation (transform, m_Camera.transform);
        }


        private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
        {
            Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;
            //dont move the rigidbody if the character is on top of it
            //if (m_CollisionFlags == CollisionFlags.Below)
            //{
               // return;
            //}

            if (body == null || body.isKinematic)
            {
                return;
            }
            if(hit.moveDirection.y < -0.3F)
            {
                return;
            }
            Vector3 pushDir = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);

            body.velocity = pushDir * pushPower;

            body.AddForceAtPosition(m_CharacterController.velocity*0.1f,   hit.point, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Crouch (which works. simply drag to FPSController

```
public class Crouch : MonoBehaviour {

CharacterController characterCollider;


void Start () 
{
    characterCollider = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
}


void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.C))
    {
        characterCollider.height = 1.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        characterCollider.height =1.8f;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with adding it to a gameobject - the compiler doesn't know anything about such a class.

Comment: I dragged this script to the FPSController in the hiearchy

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code

Comment: Click on CharacterMotor in your code, hit CTRL + . (dot), it should give you options to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

`CharaterMotor` *used to be* part of Unity's Standard Assets but not anymore. `CharaterMotor` has been deprecated for years now.

You should now be using `FirstPersonController` which is part of the Standard Assets to move your character and I suggest you stop using `CharaterMotor`.

If you have read what I said above but still want to use `CharaterMotor` then check the Unity's archive [here](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive). Select old Unity version then go to the drop down button and download the Standard Assets. You can also get it [here](https://gist.github.com/zephjc/5641540).

[image]

Comment: I have problem with CharacterMotor could you plese see my  question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245127/error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-charactermotor-could-not-be-found-ar

Comment: It can also still be found in the [Wiki - `CharacterMotor`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CharacterMotor) simply create a script with exactly that name and copy-paste the content into it.

Answer (score 0):

In a normal visual studio project, you have to add the files to the project. But Unity does that for you. When you add files, it regenerate the whole c# project. If CharacterMotor is a script in your asset folder, you shouldn't have to do anything. So try this:

- Check that CharacterMotor is in your asset folder
- Close visual studio and open it again from unity, by double clicking on a script

**Edit**
Regarding your comment about toogling crouch mode:

`Input.GetKey` return true all the time if the key is down. Instead, use `Input.GetKeyDown`. This will return true only only one frame, when the key is pressed. Set a class variable to remember of crouch is toggled, like this:

```
private void bool _crouching;

private void Update () 
{ 
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C)) 
    { 
        _crouching = !_crouching;
        characterCollider.height = _crouching ? 1.0f : 1.8f; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks, could it be that it's a private variable in the FPSController script and therefor you can't access the motor from another script? (I'm trying to get the CharacterMotor from the FPSController Script)

Comment: No, the error you get (`error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CharacterMotor' could not be found`) has nothing to do with variables accessibility. It comes before that. The class itself is not found. is CharacterMotor one of your classes or is it a reference to an old unity class like @Programmer suggested in another answer? If this is not your class, the most likely explanation is that it doesn't exist anymore and you shouldn't try to use it

Comment: it might be better to put the 'crouch and run' code directly in the FPSController script then?

Comment: What FPSController script are you talking about? You don't speak of that in your question

Comment: added it my post. it its the FPS character from Unitys standard assets. I  want my character to be able to crouch and run. thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't modify standard assets, you might lose your change when switching to a new version of Unity. You can try extending it

Comment: I've been able to make the character crouch (script in post). Now I only need to find a way to toggle instead of holding down C.

 
 void Start () 
 {
  characterCollider = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
 }
 
 
 void Update () 
 {
  if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.C))
  {
   characterCollider.height = 1.0f;
  }
  else
  {
   characterCollider.height =1.8f;
  }

 }
}

Comment: I edited my answer to solve your last comment's issue. If this works but you have other questions, it would be better to accept an answer here and make a new question instead of asking new questions in comments (One topic = One question)

Comment: Thanks. regarding your script; Should I add an boolean  _crouching; since fields cannot have a void type?

Comment: Sure, I forgot it.