# error CS0246: The type or namespace name `CharacterMotor' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly

I have script from book (Sams Teach Yourself Unity Game Development in 24 Hours) which I cannot  compile its keep trowing me error 
I add all missing Assembly reference but its still cannot find something.
here is assembly from visual studio 
[image] 
here is code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class GameControlScript : MonoBehaviour {

    //The amount of ellapsed time
    private float time = 0;

    //Flags that control the state of the game
    private bool isRunning = false;
    private bool isFinished = false;

    //place holders for the player and the spawn point
    public Transform spawnPoint;
    public GameObject player;

    //place holders for the scripts on the character controller
    public CharacterMotor motorScript;
    public MouseLook lookScript;

    //This resets to game back to the way it started
    private void InitLevel()
    {
        time = 0;
        isRunning = true;
        isFinished = false;

        //move the player to the spawn point
        player.transform.position = spawnPoint.position;

        //Allow the character controller to move and
        //look around
        motorScript.enabled = true;
        lookScript.enabled = true;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        //prevent the character controller
        //from looking around
        motorScript.enabled = false;
        lookScript.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //add time to the clock if the game
        //is running
        if(isRunning)
            time += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    //This runs when the player enters the finish
    //zone
    public void FinishedGame()
    {
        isRunning = false;
        isFinished = true;

        //freeze the character controller
        motorScript.enabled = false;
        lookScript.enabled = false;
    }


    //This section creates the Graphical User Interface (GUI)
    void OnGUI()
    {

        if(!isRunning)
        {
            string message;
            if(isFinished)
                message = "Click to Play Again";
            else
                message = "Click to Play";

            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 70, Screen.height/2, 140, 30), message))
            {
                //start the game if the user clicks to play
                InitLevel ();
            }
        }

        //If the player finished the game, show the final time
        if(isFinished)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 65, 185, 130, 40), "Your Time Was");
            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 10, 200, 20, 30), ((int)time).ToString());
        }
        //If the game is running, show the current time
        else if(isRunning)
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 65, Screen.height - 115, 130, 40), "Your Time Is");
            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 10, Screen.height - 100, 20, 30), ((int)time).ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

I add referense to 2  difrent  asemblies whish  were throwing the errors 
I add
    **using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;**

but still receiving an error 
Assets/Scripts/GameControlScript.cs(20,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `CharacterMotor' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: You need to import the standard assets package. If you have already, find the character motor script in you project's assets and check its namespace

Comment: @Draco18s but  which  assembly  and what I should use instead of CharacterMotor  and MouseLook methods ?

Comment: @Draco18s or may be you know how I should rewrite this script ?

Comment: You have to import the asset package, it is not magically available. Assets -> Import > Standard Assets

Comment: @Draco18s I did it and I have it in my project , the problem is that  C# script doesn't understand CharacterMotor

Comment: The standard assets are probable in UnityScript. You can't mix and match in the same project (not without a ton of hassle). Concert all those .js files to .cs files. Two regex replace commands over the lot of them will fix 98% of the syntax errors. Or you can Google around for a tool or already converted standard asset files.

Comment: Can you show folders inside Assets?

Comment: @Programmer last  night  i found some body  re-wright  CharacterMotor method in C# I add it  to my asset  folder and this problem go away . but I start  receiving error about that Assets/Scripts/GameControlScript.cs(35,14): error CS1061: Type `UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.MouseLook' does not contain a definition for `enabled' and no extension method `enabled' of type `UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.MouseLook' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: @Programmer sure i can how i can do it ?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].